# Bootstrap droppable Navigation menu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I create this navigation menu with Bootstrap .. 
How to make it display the dropdown menu on click for small devices but display on hover  large ones?
Also whats the way to keep the menu (with burger) of small devices, on tablets as well?

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <ul class="col-sm-3">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>
                                </li>                 
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <ul class="col-sm-4">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                          <ul class="col-sm-4">
                              <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
                              <ul class="thirdmenu">
                                  <li>Sub</li>
                                  <li>Sub</li>
                                  <li>Sub</li>
                              </ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
                              <ul class="thirdmenu">
                                  <li>SubSub</li>
                                  <li>SubSub</li>
                              </ul>
                              </li>                              
                          </ul>                          
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <ul class="col-sm-3">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>                              
                          </ul>                           
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </li>             
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Css and Js are applied by Bootstrap... Not changes yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make work on hover on larger screens you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown).
If you want a hamburger menu, you should place it in Bootstrap `.navbar` as [in official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)